# Bootstrap tab activation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content...</div>
</div>
```

And the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    activaTab('aaa');
});

function activaTab(tab){
    $('.tab-pane a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

In this case when the page is ready, the second tab will be activated but I always get a JavaScript error in the line `$('.tab-pane a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab();`

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Comment: I think you wanted `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');`, right? Also, [`id`s can't start with a number.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/70579/1935077)

Comment: Why you are not using bootstrap.js?Just include boostrap.js in your html

Comment: The error is object don't accept this property or method.
The ids in my page dont start with a number. It was my mistake, its only an example.
Bootstrap.js is included in the page

Comment: $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show'); didn't work. I edit the post with the ids changed

Comment: Can you try `$('#' + tab).tab('show');`?

Comment: $('#' + tab).tab('show'); didn't work

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Applying a selector from the `.nav-tabs` seems to be working:
See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pThn6/332/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    activaTab('aaa');
});

function activaTab(tab){
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

I would prefer @codedme's answer, since if you know which tab you want prior to page load, you should probably change the page html and not use JS for this particular task.

I tweaked the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pThn6/333/) for his answer, as well.

(If this is not working for you, please specify your setting - browser, environment, etc.)

Comment: together with bootstrap. In the template i add all the bootstrap js (including jquery.js)

Can i have any problem in this imports? Other bootstrap components like modal panel works fine

Comment: Do you have a live version of your page?

Comment: Sorry MasterAM dont have any live version. Seems that i have a problem with bootstrap.js. I have added in my page jquery.js, bootstrap.js and jsf and richfaces js. All reference to .tab() allways return a js error

Comment: Try to eliminate some of the parts until you get the relevant segment of the page. Then, with a smaller part of the page, it should be easier for you to identify the reason things are not working.

Comment: Hi. I have an example that not work. https://mega.co.nz/#!hU1ECCaQ!LaL0dBTK2eALE_R8sQzcLSUCZAkWhSnueA3mz56PvkM i used jquery 1.8.3 and the last version of bootstrap

Comment: You are using the wrong selector. use `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]')`. If you can produce the page this way, I suggest to set the proper HTML in the first place.

Comment: When I try to use this in my web app (who contains jsf and richfaces) i must add $.noConflict(). If not include this I allways get a javascript error

Comment: I updated your jsFiddles because the bootstrap URL has changed since you posted this answer.

Comment: element.focus() not work after `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is not working. If you have a specific issue, it may be more suitable to create it as a separate question (you can reference this question or answer in it). Then, I can try to answer it if I can.

Comment: used $('#navtabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show'); because if nav-tabs class do exist in my css, navtabs is for sure the id of my tabs navbar :)

Comment: substitute nav-tabs with nav-pills if necessary :)

Comment: In some environments, you have to escape the double quotes for proper concatenation like $('.nav-tabs a[href=\"#' + tab + '\"]').tab('show'); . Might be useful for someone :)

Comment: It is not working after submission of form with JQuery

Comment: Since this has been posted it is no longer working. Try fiddle return console Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function

Answer (score 28):

Perform a click on the link to the tab anchor whenever the page is ready i.e.

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').trigger('click');
```

Or in vanilla JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click();
```

Comment: Simple solution and straight to point.
For those who might have issue, wrap it into a document ready function. i.e `$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').trigger('click');
});`

Answer (score 25):

This one is quite straightforward from w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp

```
// Select tab by name
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#home"]').tab('show')

// Select first tab
$('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show') 

// Select last tab
$('.nav-tabs a:last').tab('show') 

// Select fourth tab (zero-based)
$('.nav-tabs li:eq(3) a').tab('show')
```

Answer (score 13):

Add an id attribute to a html tag

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab" id="tab_aaa">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab" id="tab_bbb">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab" id="tab_ccc">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content...</div>
</div>
```

Then using JQuery

```
$("#tab_aaa").tab('show');
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<div class="tabbable">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="aaa">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Add active class to any li element you want to be active after page load.
And also adding active class to content div is needed ,fade in classes are useful for a smooth transition.

Comment: I need active one tab depending of a condition. Not allways the first tab will be selected when the page is load

Comment: I think that you should also give the content dive the `active` class.

Comment: @MasterAM yes you are right and also fade class to have a smooth transition .Edited

Comment: I add the class="active" to the first tab but the javascript error didn't disapear. The tab take the active style but the content didn't appear

Comment: I edited the code please use this one.you need to also add active class to content div element.

Answer (score 4):

Having just struggled with this - I'll explain my situation.

I have my tabs within a bootstrap modal and set the following on load (pre the modal being triggered):

`$('#subMenu li:first-child a').tab('show');`

Whilst the tab was selected the actual pane wasn't visible. As such you need to add `active` class to the pane as well:

`$('#profile').addClass('active');`

In my case the pane had `#profile` (but this could have easily been `.pane:first-child`) which then displayed the correct pane.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine on Bootstrap 5.1.3.

```
$('#nav-profile-tab').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not select active tab first then active the selected tab content ?
       1. Add class 'active' to the < li > element of tab first .
       2. then use set 'active' class to selected div.

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
        SelectTab(1); //or use other method  to set active class to tab
        ShowInitialTabContent();

    });
    function SelectTab(tabindex)
    {
        $('.nav-tabs li ').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav-tabs li').eq(tabindex).addClass('active'); 
        //tabindex start at 0 
    }
    function FindActiveDiv()
    {  
        var DivName = $('.nav-tabs .active a').attr('href');  
        return DivName;
    }
    function RemoveFocusNonActive()
    {
        $('.nav-tabs  a').not('.active').blur();  
        //to >  remove  :hover :focus;
    }
    function ShowInitialTabContent()
    {
        RemoveFocusNonActive();
        var DivName = FindActiveDiv();
        if (DivName)
        {
            $(DivName).addClass('active'); 
        } 
    }
```