# Changing active Bootstrap 3 tab using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was experimenting with programatically changing tabs using jQuery. I tried to implement the solution given by @MasterAM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830590/bootstrap-tab-activation-with-jquery). However, the Chrome console shows the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="click-me-div">Click Me</div>

 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#fruits" data-toggle="tab">I like Fruits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#veggies" data-toggle="tab">I like Veggies Too</a></li>
    <li><a href="#samosas" data-toggle="tab">But Samosa's Rock</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="fruits">Apple, Kiwi, Watermellon</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="veggies">Kale, Spinach, Pepper</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="samosas">Awesome, Spine Tingling, Explosive</div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click-me-div").click(function() {
        alert('yes, the click actually happened');
        ('.nav-tabs a[href="#samosas"]').tab('show');
    });
});
```

The desired outcome is that, if I click "Click Me", the active tab should change to the "samosas" tab.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You left out the jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click-me-div").click(function() {
        alert('yes, the click actually happened');
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#samosas"]').tab('show');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k88Lf/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

You can use `onclick()` function and path id name of tab.

```
<a onclick='ActivTab("Security")' class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Security" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" id='Security'>Security</a>


    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             ActivTab('Security');
         });
         function ActivTab(id){
//           $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
             $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
         };
     </script>
```

Comment: Hi Ayman, welcome to SO! It might be a good idea to explain what your snippet is doing and why you have done what you did so that newcomers will find it easier to understand.