# How do I make a particular tab active on the next page based on a user's click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For example, from from /index.html, I want to take them to another page, /list

Within /list, there is a pill nav

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

Depending on what they clicked from index.html, I would like different list items active. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: You would add the `active` class to the `tab` in the `pill nav` - it you add your code in a [mcve] it's easier to spot where the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send number in parameter from index.html to list.html and then get that number and show tab according to that number.

add number to link in index.html like this

```html
<a href="list.html?number=1">Item 1</a>
<a href="list.html?number=2">Item 2</a>
<a href="list.html?number=3">Item 3</a>
```

add this code in list.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var url_string = window.location.href; 
var url = new URL(url_string);

var number = url.searchParams.get("number");
    activeTab(number);
});

function activeTab(tab){
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#item' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

Comment: Your solution depends on an external library, namely `jQuery`. Would be nice, to explain why you add it and how to implement that external source.

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski above solutions will work for bootstrap nav tabs

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find which tab to activate (Maybe using fragment url, the part with "#", that you can read using some plugin [like this](http://www.benalman.com/projects/jquery-url-utils-plugin/)) then activate the tabe [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830590/bootstrap-tab-activation-with-jquery) :

```
$('get your tab').tab('show');
```